# Problema subiendo archivo al servidor

Tags: laravel

Tengo un formulario con varios campos de texto y dos campos tipo file, en el subo archivos PDF, la ruta me la guarda en la base de datos, pero los archivos no suben al directorio, también los otros campos. No me muestra ningún error, hace el proceso como si todo funcionara.

```
$file = new File;
$file_01 = $request->file('file_01');
$file_02 = $request->file('file_02');
$path_01 = Storage::disk('public')->put('files',  $file_01);
$path_02 = Storage::disk('public')->put('files',  $file_02);
$file->fill(['file_01' => $path_01])->save();
$file->fill(['file_02' => $path_02])->save();
$file->fill(['user_id' => $user->id])->save();
$file->save();
```

PD: Los demás campos van a otra base de datos y funciona bien (Los campos de textos).

Comment: Acabo de ver que me los está guardando en el directorio Storage y no Public, tengo apuntado el directorio Public para guardar unas imágenes y lo hace bien, debería tener los permisos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlos accesibles, debes crear un enlace simbólico de `public/storage` a `storage/app/public`:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Estaba leyendo sobre eso, se guaradarían en Storage y los leo en Public? o se guardan en ambos? Hice un Disco en FileSystem y al parecer está funcionando

Comment: En teoría se guardan en ambas rutas, pero primero en `storage/app/public`, y al crear un `link` o `enlace`, todos los archivos o carpetas subidos a `storage/app/public` también se verán dentro de `public/storage`

Comment: Evitaría esa opción porque en este caso son muchos archivos y ocuparía mucho espacio en disco. Gracias, lo tomo en cuenta para otro proyecto que no requiera subir tantos archivos.

Comment: No me expliqué bien, sólo se guarda un link al archivo, no se guarda dos veces. Es por ello que es un enlace al archivo.

Comment: Okey, muchas gracias! Sí es lógico con el nombre link.

Comment: Siempre que he usado `storage` automáticamente me lo guarda en `Public`, en este proyecto no.